# Writing fractions in Graphics

Tags: plotting, formatting, subscript

I want to write a fraction which contains subscript in a graph.  But my code doesn't work.

```
 Graphics[{Text[
 Style["-Subscript[\[CapitalGamma],r] /v", Large, Bold, White], 
 Automatic, {2.7, 13}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminate the quotation marks (which mean you want the verbatim code), fix the closing bracket and make the text Blue so you can see it:

```
Graphics[
 Text[Style[-Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], r] /v, Large, Bold, Blue], 
  Automatic, {0, 0}]]
```

Also... there's no need for `Automatic`.

This looks much nicer, to my eye:

```
Graphics[
 Text[Style[ 
   "\!\(\*FractionBox[SubscriptBox[\(\[CapitalGamma]\), \(r\)], \
\(v\)]\)", Large, Bold, Blue, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 0}]]
```

Comment: How can I multily numerator by x? I tried Graphics[Text[
  Style["\!\(\* FractionBox[ SubscriptBox[\(\[CapitalGamma]\), \(r\)] \
x, \(v\)]\)", Large, Bold, Black, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 0}]] but it doesn't work

Comment: `Graphics[Text[
  Style["\!\(\* FractionBox[SubscriptBox[\(x \[CapitalGamma]\), \
\(r\)], \(v\)]\)", Large, Bold, Blue, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 0}]]`

Comment: Sorry, but another question, is it possible to write your previous comment with gamma ^2_r?

Comment: Why switch from expressions to strings? Just `-x Subscript[Γ, r] /v` would be a lot easier to comprehend.

Comment: @AlbertNestler `-x Subsuperscript[Γ, r, 2]/v` would work.

Comment: @CarlWoll I prefer to write the fraction as David did.